# How do I create different namespaces for USB wifi client?

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to use my in-built Wi-Fi card and an external USB Wi-Fi adapter to be run on separate namespaces. I have checked that the drivers are up to date, kernel version is latest (using Ubuntu 14.04).

I used

```
sudo ip netns add WLAN0
```

Followed by

```
sudo ip netns exec WLAN0 bash
```

For the in-built Wi-Fi card. Then on a new terminal, when I try a `iw dev`, the output that I get does not show me the MAC address of both Wi-Fi interfaces I have. I can however, go ahead and assign this WLAN0 namespace to wlan0 (in-built Wi-Fi card).

Turning OFF inbuilt Wi-Fi through BIOS setting, lets me use the external USB Wi-Fi adapter. However, when I do a iw dev, the Wi-Fi adapter isn't listed. ifconfig does list wlan1. Due to no output for `iw dev`, I am unable to assign a new namespace to this interface.

`iw dev` output for in-built Wi-Fi card is:

```
phy#0
     Interface wlan0
     ifindex 3
     type managed
```

`iw dev` output for external USB Wi-Fi adapter returns nothing.

Can someone help?